# Can we use return rdr using a stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have table as follows

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_address, emp_salary, emp_rating
```

I would like to get all the above rows ... I have written stored procedure as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fetch_empdata]
@empid int
AS
SELECT * 
FROM emptable
WHERE emp_id = @empid;
```

```
string connection = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbase + ";User ID=" + userid + ";Password=" + password;

conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(storedprocedure, conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", empid));

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Is there a way to use a command return rdr?
I would like to return all the values of this table to some other class.
Or do I have to explicitly move var empid = rdr("EMPID")?

Comment: what is the var `storedprocedure` ??

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you want to create a .NET function that will return a SqlDataReader object?

Comment: @Felipe, I'm guessing it is a string that has his stored proc name in it.  I believe rdr is a `SqlDataReader` object.  He definitely left some important code out.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? Why do you want to return a reader?

Comment: I am using a stored procedure to fetch the emp info...after fetching the results...my results are stored in rdr...I have to return all the these columns to next class....I was thinking whether i can use return rdr or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get your `SqlDataReader` like this:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

you now need to enumerate over the result set:

```
while(rdr.Read())
{
    int emp_id = rdr.GetInt(0);
    string emp_name = rdr.GetString(1);
    string emp_address = rdr.GetString(2);
    decimal emp_salary = rdr.GetDecimal(3);
    int emp_rating = rdr.GetInt(4);

    // do something with those variables.... then move on to next row
}
```

What you do with those variables is entirely up to you - whatever makes sense for you. Stick them into an object and put all objects retrieved into a `List<Employee>` or something - whatever you want.

Also: you might need to check for NULL values, too - before calling `.GetString/.GetInt` etc. - otherwise you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you are doing it right, if you are setting your variable `storedprocedure` to the value `"fetch_empdata"`

Then, to get the value, you could do

```
if(rdr.Read()) {
    string emp_id = rdr.GetString(0);
}
```

being `0` the index of your "EMPID" column

**EDIT:** A good thing to keep in mind is the fact that you are using `SELECT *` to retrieve data, which is not a good practice, as any change in the table columns will result in a change in the `select` return, and could also break your application.

A good approach would be to explicitly inform which columns you want to return, and the order of them, such as

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME, ...
```